# Curious bot-questions recently

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This is the second or third time I see one of these questions. They seem to be written by bots and get instantly deleted. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374371/clone-testing-in-a-group-project) is the link to the deleted question in the following image.

[image]

Any idea what's going on? I'm curious.

Comment: That somehow reminds me of https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2594/2254 , but probably not the same ballpark. They must know that here on stack overflow, spam bots will be fought off by more sophisticated bots (the latter are sometimes "moderators", but ... meh ;-))

Comment: It's happening. They'll take over. Time to befriend with your toaster.

Comment: Could someone creating a bot / API for posting to Stack Overflow for a school assignment / hackathon project

Comment: The "console.log()" is quite interesting too, as if they are trying to XSS pen-test.

Comment: Seems worth raising a flag over. If nothing else, so that a mod can tell this user that they're going to get themselves post-banned if they keep doing it.

Comment: But hey what if he created the post by his own hands?

Comment: @Darkonaut [Would you like any toast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRq_SAuQDec)?

Answer (score 17):

I feel obligated to point out that far more time has been consumed *here* than should have ever been consumed by a few API test posts* that lived for all of twenty seconds.

We're a developer website with an API. Sometimes people want to play with stuff. That's fine; I don't see any evidence here that the testing was excessive or disruptive (except for this thread, which isn't exactly the tester's fault).

I'll gladly take the minuscule disruption to a few people's realtime feeds in exchange for the possibility of someone developing a useful tool.

---

<sup>*They might not have been from the API - that's fine, there are legit reasons to make test posts from the web interface.</sup>

Comment: …and there’s no possibility to provide a sandbox for those API testers? You’re not the only website with an API. But it’s the first I heard of saying, experimenting on the live site is fine…

Comment: Sure, it's *possible*... but several points: (1) Stack Overflow has different behavior, technically, than other sites in ways that matter to tool developers, (2) Q&A development work is hard to come by at the moment, I wouldn't want to spend it on something like a sandbox for the three meta posts a year complaining of this, (3) even if there *was* a sandbox, forcing tool developers (who are contributing in their spare time) to use it isn't something I'm interested in doing.

Comment: And (4), it's a simple pro/con formula. The pros outweigh the cons, by a lot. If there were dozens or hundreds of these? Maybe that'd change, but there simply aren't. This isn't worth anyone's energy to worry about.

Comment: Sorry, but that’s ridiculous. Stackexchange is running 173 sites, so what actual cons would creating a 174th site have? There even *is* already a site for creating and disposing sub-sites, area51.stackexchange.com. Further, developers might be even more rational than you assume, i.e. don’t need to be “forced” to use the sandbox, if there was one. As these developers might see the advantage of not needing to insert the “this is a test, please ignore, we will delete soon, bla bla bla” prose.

Comment: Every additional site creates overhead at a bunch of levels, especially one with no active userbase to provide moderation. A dedicated sandbox site that's open to the public simply isn't going to happen. Stack Apps is the closest we're going to get, and as said earlier, it has behavior that differs from Stack Overflow in some important ways.

Comment: Isn't there a sandbox somewhere for testing this stuff?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Stack Apps is probably okay, and there's the MSE sandbox, but neither is perfect for testing some categories of things. Read the comments above for more details.

Answer (score 7):

This looks to me like a simple test of the SO API. Someone who's developing an application or website, and testing if they can successfully post questions here. I would not worry too much.

EDIT: The OP question is simply

> 'Any idea what's going on? I'm curious'

... And except for the `console.log`, I don't see any reason to suspect something else than a genuine test of the API. The simple fact that multiple occurrences were seen doesn't make a big difference, we all know that when testing/developping, we are likely going to hit the same test several times during the development process.

Comment: Actually, given the fact that someone has decided to take away some amount of attention away from legitimate questions with their tests, I'm *quite* concerned.  Probably not enough to do more than shout from my couch, but concerned enough to note that maybe these kinds of tests don't need to be happening on the main site.  *Surely* there exists a sandbox for the person to get their satisfactory test, and if there isn't, then make a post on Meta about the *lack* of a sandbox instead of assuming that it's okay.

Comment: @Makoto You browse SO on your couch? I laud your productivity as I comment from bed.

Comment: <s>productivity</s> addiction

Comment: @TylerH:  Well, my phone is next to me when I'm on my couch while I'm playing Breath of the Wild, so...yeah...